# Querying a wordpress database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Can anyone see whats wrong with this syntax? I've consulted the wordpress codex page and the syntax seems to be correct..

```
$result = $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}users WHERE username = %s AND password = %s, array( $username, $password )"));
```

Thanks

Comment: Your `"` are at the wrong place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
 $result = $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM     {$wpdb->prefix}users WHERE username = %s AND password = %s", array( $username, $password )));
```

your quotes are incorrect.